# Is it possible to write code like this in C++11 without using boost?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, lambda

a while ago I stumbled upon a 
following line of code:

```
 return accumulate(s, s + size, char(), (_1 ^ _2));
```

It was using boost headers, but I always thought it is very very very elegant (note that lambda does not have input params named, so it is super short. :)
Please note that I know C++11 has lambda functions, this is not about lambdas, it is about this nice short syntax.

Comment: I'm not sure your question, `^` can be overloaded so it is possible.

Comment: What do you mean by `^`? What it means in C and C++, or what it means in other languages?

Comment: code does xor checksum :), so ^ is normal ^ ...   ^_^

Comment: How much machinery are you willing to put behind it?  You can't do it out of the box, obviously.  But you can also obviously build a library that takes care of it, like Boost.Lambda does.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley :( I was wondering if std supports it.... since it has _1 _2 placeholders  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/placeholders

Comment: Those are for use with `std::bind`, which allows you to rearrange (or hard code) arguments to a pre-existing functor.  It does not provide anything like the on-the-fly custom functor generation that Boost.Lambda provides.  Its use here would not look anything like the example you provided.  It would be extremely unappealing, and unnecessary, since you can just pass an `std::bit_xor` object. No need for parameter rearrangement.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley hi, this is not about xor, it is just example... BTW make your comment A and Ill accept it.

Comment: *"Is this possible in C++11"* - Well, of course it is, build a library similar to *Boost.Lambda*. Since you already seem to be acquainted with C++11's functional facilities, you already seem to know that it isn't possible right out of the box. So what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to do it without Boost is to reinvent the Boost components that create it. How could you possibly have the syntax of a Boost component without an implementation of that Boost component?

The language solution is lambdas, and if you don't like them, then it's time to either use Boost or steal this specific part of it.

Comment: i thought ISO committee  is smart enough to implement a cool feature... not the first time i made that mistake :P Though tbh I guessed it cant be done, but I wanted to be sure since like I said I really like the syntax.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: If nobody makes a proposal, the committee can't do shit about it not being in the language.

Comment: *"I thought ISO committee is smart enough to implement a cool feature"* - Of course they are. And you know what, they're even smart enough to not implement each and every feature one might find *"cool"*. *Boost* is a vast selection of feature-rich libraries and not a de facto model for the next standard. We finally have lambdas. Ok, they're not as *neat* as you example, but they integrate well into the existing language and don't obfuscate the language syntax into something completely different. And they make library solutions like *Boost.Lambda* obsolete, If you still want it, just use it.

Comment: @ChristianRau well it is actually the other way around, Boost Lambda made C++11 lambda syntax obsolete the moment it was standardized. :D But tbh I dont really care to waste time arguing if the syntax I like is better than the syntax you like because it is not a scientifically measurable thing :)

Comment: @Xeo Isnt like Herb the committee and the proposal writer?

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl I think we don't agree about the meaning of the word *"standardized"* for the ubiquity of a feature. But nevermind.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: C++11 lambda syntax is far more generalized and useful than Boost.Lambda. The entire reason for creating C++11 lambdas *was because Boost.Lambda wasn't good enough*.

Comment: @DeadMG example ? And still it doesnt make sense for that to be reason not to have short syntax...

Answer (score 6):

With hard coded types...

```
return accumulate(s, s+size, char(), [](char l, char r){ return l ^ r; });
```

When [generic lambdas](http://isocpp.org/blog/2013/04/trip-report-iso-c-spring-2013-meeting) are allowed (C++14)...

```
return accumulate(s, s+size, char(), [](auto l, auto r){ return l ^ r; });
```

For now, [std::bit_xor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bit_xor)...

```
return accumulate(s, s+size, char(), bit_xor<char>());
```

Comment: I know that is possible, Im looking for syntax that works without defining input params to the lambda...